# How do I link 2 JSP pages together?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Just wondering what the easiest way to connect 2 jsp pages together, I have one page and I need to have it link to another page when a customer clicks something.  Now can I create a link like in html or do I need to make a button or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can just create a link specifying the url of the other jsp
for example if other jsp is in same directory you could just use

```
<a href="b.jsp">Goto B</a>
```